# Disable Xcode's built-in fuzzy auto-complete

Tags: xcode

I have just updated to Xcode 7.3, but the built-in fuzzy auto-complete drives me crazy.

How do I turn this feature off?

Comment: I'm still on 7.2, but these settings are in Preferences > Text Editing > Code completion

Comment: That was the first place I look, there is no option there to remove that feature. [link](http://imgur.com/u37GNac)

Comment: What if you uncheck 'Suggest completions while typing'

Comment: then Xcode only pops the suggestions when you press the esc button (and still have fuzzy suggestions).